# Object in Async doInBackground method is empty

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I currently have a object called AsyncObj which i assign 3 arraylists to later pass to my asynctask. In the asynctask i have a constructor which assignes both objects and later use in the doInBackground method.

The problem is the object is empty inside the doInBackground method and i dont seem to know why. While when i check the size of the arraylist inside the construct of the AsyncTask it's fine.

MyObject:

```
public class AsyncObj {

    ArrayList<Float> valuesX;
    ArrayList<Float> valuesY;
    ArrayList<Float> valuesZ;

    public AsyncObj(ArrayList<Float> a, ArrayList<Float> b, ArrayList<Float> c) {
        this.valuesX = a;
        this.valuesY = b;
        this.valuesZ = c;
    }
}
```

My AsyncTask:

```
class SendHttp extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    private AsyncObj asyncObj1;

    SendHttp(AsyncObj asyncObj){
        this.asyncObj1 = asyncObj;
        Log.v("TAG","In constructor: "+asyncObj1.valuesX.size());
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }


    public Void doInBackground(Void...voids){
        Log.v("TAG",""+asyncObj1.valuesX.size());
        String url = createQuery(asyncObj1.valuesX,asyncObj1.valuesY,asyncObj1.valuesZ);
        try{
            final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET,
                    url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.v("TAG","Error");
                        }
                    }
            );
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            Log.v("TAG",url);
            Log.v("TAG","In SendHTTP");
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.v("TAG",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think  Volley request is already asynchronous you do not have to use a `AsyncTask`.  And to answer your code is incomplete . Add how you are calling `execute()`.

Comment: I simply create the object: AsyncObj asyncObj = new AsyncObj(ValuesX,ValuesY,ValuesZ); and then call
new SendHttp(asyncObj).execute();

Comment: Did you debug the size of values ?? Check it . Debug your code . And as I said you do not need an AsyncTask . Read about volley request . I think it's already asynchronous .

Comment: I already am, Inside the contructor i consult the size of the array and it's the same as when i created the object. The problem is when i consult the size of the object inside the doInBackground method and it's 0, as if the same variable "asyncobj1" is diferent inside the method then outside.